# Graph Results via Non GUI mode in JMeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, listener, performance-testing

Is there any possibilities to get my below mentioned **Graph Results** in JMeter test, which is executed in non GUI mode. I can extract its values using csv, but we need to run the test in non GUI mode to get dashboard results also. Any possibilities for this ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given you [run your JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) like:

```
jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l results.jtl
```

Once test is finished you should be able to open JMeter GUI, add [Graph Results](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Graph_Results) listener, locate `results.jtl` file using "Browse" button and you will see the chart.

Also there is an option to generate some charts in unattended manner using [Command-Line Graph Plotting Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) project, see [Automatically generating nice graphs at end of your Load Test with Apache JMeter and JMeter-Plugins](http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/automatically-generating-nice-graphs-at-end-of-your-load-test-with-apache-jmeter-and-jmeter-plugins/) guide for details.

Comment: Is there any possibility to convert my .jtl file to html dashboards/charts ?

Comment: You can generate HTML Reporting Dashboard like `jmeter -g results.jtl -o /path/to/dashboard/folder`, see [Generating Reports](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report) chapter for more information. Alternatively you can upload your .jtl results file to a 3rd-party analysis service like [BM.Sense](http://sense.blazemeter.com/)

Comment: I find that the same exact test plan run in GUI mode generates a graph in Graph Results that plots all the measurements (Average, Median, Throughput, Variance) whereas when I run that test plan in non GUI mode and then load the resulting .jtl file into the Graph Results listener afterwards, only the Throughput is plotted. Has anyone seen this before? Workarounds?

Comment: Hi I have the .jtl file already downloaded from my non GUI test scripts reposts, is there any way that i can generate graph results from this .jtl file and save it graphically??

Answer (score 1):

There is a 3rd party plugin that allows you to monitor a NON-GUI test from a browser without further work.

After installing the plugin with [JMeter-Plugins manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/install/Install/) following this [documentation](https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/ubik-load-pack-observability-plugin/).

Add the **UbikLoadPack observality plugin** to your test plan:

[image: Add > Listener > UbikLoadPack Observability Plugin]

The listener will be added, you can then adjust properties:

[image: UbikLoadPack Observability Plugin configuration]

You’ll be able to follow it from browser at url:

- http://jmeter_host:9090/ulp-observability

In the browser, you'll have a web page showing:

- A set of Live graphs for average response times, percentiles, error rate

[image: Graphs]

- Live Summary metrics from test start

[image: Summary metrics]

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to write web app based on Django to work with test results, do an online monitoring, etc. (kinda dashboard) for load tests which runned in Jmeter console mode (incl. distributive testing).
Maybe you will want to participate in development or so :):
https://github.com/v0devil/JMeter-Control-Center